# QProcessBar in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4.7

I want to build a progress bar that shows the progress of one process which is executed by `QProcess::execute(QString);` in my GUI.

Problem is when I execute it, then my GUI hangs and I can't do anything within it.

At least, I would like to to show a loading image which shows the something is happening behind the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `QProcess::start` rather than execute.  Execute will block until the process exits.

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Check the QProcess documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to use threads if your GUI is hanging, have a look at `QFuture`

Comment: There's no need to use a seperate thread.  You can start the process asynchronously and use signals from QProcess to get notifications about its changes in state.